# What beer is the beekeeper seeking?

Tags: fiz

In order to get the White Bee's Honey, I need to brew a certain beer but all I have is this clue:

> I've heard tales of Germany's
>   people who act like my bees.
>   Post winter's leave they swarm to please
>   newly awakened thirst for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beekeeper wants what Germans drink in the spring, so check out the rotating seasonal German festhall at that time of year.

> Or just read the spoiler and make him a Maibock.

Comment: hmm... making a 2000 quality mouse trap maibock is now going to be my goal! :P

Comment: That isn't actually too hard... And you've got a bigger quality challenge coming right down the pipe.