# What is the clue/recipe for Fiz lager?

Tags: fiz

Is there a way I can get the clue for the Fiz recipe? I can't remember what the old man said and can't find it anywhere.

I would prefer the clue (maybe a screen shot of it) but if not I'll just take the recipe. I have all the stuff for it just can put it together.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz actually since this one was asked first the other is a dupe of this one.

Comment: @spartacus the other question is much higher quality, which matters more than a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the hints for the recipe by tapping on the question marks.

[image]

The hints are:

- Top-Left: **Key to Friendship**.
  Solution:

  > The key to Eddy's Bodega. Complete the event **Eddy's Brewdega?**.
- Top-Right: **Symbol of Pride**.
  Solution:

  > The Uprum Champion's Pendant. Complete the event **Cyrus Uprum's Copper Clemency Competition**.
- Centre: **Prehistoric Yeast**.
  Solution:

  > Purchase the Prehistoric Yeast from Z the next time she comes by for 25 000 coins.
- Bottom-Left: **Banshee's Tears**.
  Solution:

  > Successfully stock the missing beer at The Twelve Bells and wait for it to expire.
- Bottom-Right: **White Bees' Honey**.
  Solution:

  > Complete the event **A Riddle So Sweet**. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147525/) for details.

Comment: Does the recipe come up incomplete in the list cause I don't have anything in my recipe list(maybe a glitch).

Comment: Never mind I found it. I'm an idiot was there all along.

Comment: What if i cant buy Prehistoric Yeast from Z?? I am stuck there!